# Updating nested documents in mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongodb collection that looks something like the following:

```
_id: ObjectId("123456789")
continent_name: "Europe"
continent_id: "001"
countries: Array
  0
    country_name: "France"
    country_id: "011"
    cities: Array
      0
        city_name: "Paris"
        city_id: "101"
      1
        city_name: "Maseille"
        city_id: "102"
  1
    country_name: "England"
    country_id: "012"
    cities: Array
      0
        city_name: "London"
        city_id: "201"
      1
        city_name: "Bath"
        city_id: "202"
```

And so on for other continents>countries>cities.
I'm unclear on what approach to take when updating this collection.

Let's say I run my data collection again and discover a new city in England, resulting in an array for [London, Bath, Manchester], how do I update the value of Europe>England>[] pythonically without touching France?

Is it possible to search `where(continent=Europe && country=England)`?

My current working theory is to do something like the following:

```
def mongo_add_document(continent, country, cities):
    data= {
        "continent_name": continent["name"],
        "continent_id": continent["id"],
        "countries": [
            {
                "country_name": country["name"],
                "country_id": country["id"],
                "cities": [
                    {"city_id": city["id"], "city_id": city["id"]} for city in cities
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

    cities.find_one_and_update(
        {"continent_id": continent["id"]},
        data,
        upsert=True
    )
```

But my concern is this will overwrite other countries in the continent document.

Comment: Why not use $push to add a city instead of updating all the data? They you can use $ as a placeholder for the array. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#mongodb-update-up.-

Comment: I'm relatively new to mongodb and nosql databases. Could you provide an example of how you'd do this?
I did consider using the mongodb aggregate function, which returns the correct element, but now I'm stuck on how to update it.

Comment: I added an answer with an example query

Answer (score 1):

```
db.getCollection('cities')
  .updateOne({"continent_name": "Europe", "countries.country_name": "England", "countries.cities.city_name" :  {$ne: "Manchester"}}, 
             {$push: {"countries.$.cities": {"city_name": "Manchester", "city_id":"whatever"}}})
```

Comment: I think the solution will be based on this. The only issue I'm having with this is that if my collected data contains cities already in the document, it will create a duplicate. I tried using upsert=True, but the duplicates were still present. Given the size of the collected data, I'm concerned that filtering for existing records might incur long runtimes.
Is it possible to just overwrite the entire contents of the cities array with a new array?

Comment: Something like:

`{$set: {"countries.???.cities.$[]": [{"city_name": "Manchester", "city_id":"whatever"}, {"city_name": London"...}]}}`

Comment: Updated to make it distinct. You don't want to update the entire array because if you'll ever have two concurrent updates one of them will be lost.

Comment: Data collection is infrequent and is guaranteed to include existing data, so overwriting the existing list shouldn't lose anything.